# Is there a standard PoE+ input symbol for a product label?

Tags: symbol, standard, poe

I was expecting to easily find this. However, unlike other safety symbols (such as double insulation / Class 2) I cannot seem to find a lead.

Was convinced this would fall under some sort of safety as it is 44~57 V 25 W although, since it is not a PSE I can imagine it slipping through.

I'm looking for a PoE+ (IEEE802.3at PD) input specification to the device (no output, pure consumer).

Comment: Are you looking for something like the [Ethernet Alliance's PoE certification](https://ethernetalliance.org/poecert/) symbols?

Comment: Hi @Null, that's certification only as far as I can see. I am looking for something much simpler that would merely indicate that the product is powered by PoE+. Since writing 'Input: 54V' would be meaningless since there's a handshake protocol to conform to. (unlike for barrel jack inputs where voltage, Power/current rating and a polarity symbol would suffice)